# Launch XQuartz app via Automator

Tags: automator, homebrew, x11, xquartz

I'm trying to launch [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) (installed via Homebrew) via an app shortcut, ideally ending up in my Applications folder. A recommended way to launch console apps in Mountain Lion seems to be using Automator.

Running `/usr/local/bin/meld` in a terminal starts XQuartz and meld launches fine. My Automator script looks like:

[image: Automator script]

But when running all I get is the 'Run Shell Script failed' error. XQuartz doesn't launch. If XQuartz is already running meld still doesn't start.

1. Is there a way to get more useful (stdout/stderr) from Automator actions?
2. What does the shell do differently do launch XQuartz and apps within it?

Edit: I can get it to work by using `open /usr/local/bin/meld` in my action, but I then also get a Terminal window (which I don't want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aha. Looks like Homebrew wants to run meld via it's own Python, rather than the system one. Terminal sets this up correctly, but obviously Automator doesn't.

Solution: use Run Shell Script in Automator with:

```
/usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/meld
```

Comment: Can you mark this as the solution please?

Comment: @Lyken not for a couple more days :)